# How to open folder from web page

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0

I want to open folder from web page on clicking on a button.

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Response.Redirect("file://C://inetpub//wwwroot//myproject");
}
```

Please suggest me proper code in C# for open myproject  folder.

Comment: Cannot be done. A web application does not have access to the local machine's filesystem.

Comment: Are you looking at allowing someone to upload a file to you web server?

Comment: no . I want to open myproject, my all web pages are stored into myproject folder .

Comment: What you want to do makes *no sense whatsoever*. It would be like having a button in Microsoft Office Word which opens up a folder on the *source code* on the machine of one of the developers of it... which is meaningless.

Comment: No, I want to open/explore myproject folder  using windows Explorer.

Answer (score 5):

**This can be ONLY done in IE**, no other browser has access to file system. You can assign the path to href of an anchor tag, and it should work.

```
<a href="file://LAP6//C$">Open</a>
```

Comment: Right. In Chrome you will get `Not allowed to load local resource` error.

Comment: I want to open folder on clicking button .

Comment: You can do this, in javascript, when button is clicked call `window.open("file://LAP6//C$", null, null, false);` **This will not work if you are opening `C://inetpub//` or `C://`**

Comment: Nope. You can do this in Javascript, as I suggested.

Answer (score -1):

If you're looking at adding functionality to your website so that a user can upload files to it then look at [this project on MSDN](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/323246). It'll show you how to do this with an example ASP.NET project.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe this statement can help you:

```
 System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(@"C:\");
```

Comment: Sorry, that method don't work on client side (MSDN confirmed and explained the fact). So, my way for resolving this problem is: using javascript.

Comment: Code: <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" ...onClientClick="return my_()f".../> <script type="text/javascript"> function my_f() {window.open("file://1.1.1.1/");}</script>